# How do I dynamically insert an iframe in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I dynamically insert an iframe in a div using jQuery?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div").html("<iframe src='http://google.com'><iframe>");  
});
```

I tried the above code, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Works for me.  Have you got a reference to the Jquery library in the page?

Comment: As mentioned below remember to close your iframe tag. Also note that because Google is now sending an "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN" response header you will get an empty iframe, therefore test with another src.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What you have works: http://jsfiddle.net/cUSVj/

Though keep in mind you can't do much with it after it's created if it's in not in the same domain, this is due to restrictions in place per the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

*Edit:* I was closing the tag thinking it was a paste error, you are indeed missing a `/` in your `</iframe>` closing tag...this will/won't work depending on how generous the browser is.    Make sure to close it correctly so your HTML is valid, otherwise you'll have cross-browser issues, *if* it works to begin with.

Comment: @lam3r4370 - It depends how that environment handlers an unclosed tag, see my updated answer, I re-read your question, didn't see it the first time, just blindly fixed it in jsfiddle before.

Comment: Yes ,I tested it "inside" phpDesigner and that is because it didn't work...
P.S:Yes ,it is mine paste error.

Comment: +1 for showing me a new awesome thing, jsfiddle.net.  What rock have I been under?

Answer (score 7):

you did not close the iframe tag

```
<iframe>
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 4):

I've used it like this and it works well ;-)

```
$(".div").html("<iframe width='850' height='450' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' src='http://yourlocation.com'></iframe>");  
$(".div").css("display","block");
```

Comment: That will not restrict user to answer question at all.This is a community and a user can answer any time if he think he can give a try

Answer (score 2):

The actual jquery code looks fine, you may not be referencing the div correctly i.e.

```
#div - would be an element with the id "div"
.div - would be an element with the class "div"
```

Answer (score 0):

It works, I just tested it, what you might need is give jquery the id/class of the div you want to insert the iframe

eg. (id)

```
$("#myDiv").html("<iframe src='http://google.com'></iframe>");
```

eg. (class)

```
$(".myDiv").html("<iframe src='http://google.com'></iframe>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is working fine.

Check here : http://jsbin.com/arolo3/2/edit

You should close the iframe tag. It might be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>

<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>


<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#frameDiv").html("<iframe src='http://google.com'></iframe>");  
    });


</script>
<p>An IFrame should appear here</p>
<div id="frameDiv" style="width: 400px; height: 400px;"></div>

</body>
```