# Iframes Vs. Frames

Tags: asp.net, html

I understand that frames are a lot more typing work to implement than Iframes, and that they require a lot more styling than Iframes. I am currently working on a website which must download some content (in fact, an entire set of webpages) from another website, one - by - one of course depending on the user's action on the main website. Iframes seem to be a short and rowdy way to implement this requirement, but what I am worried about is performance and integrity.

I would like some advice on what I would rather use when the following criteria is met:

1. The pages that must be downloaded onto my webpage are quite large (width and height)
2. Contains multiple images
3. Experiences occasional downtimes (maintainence)

any ideas for a man in wonder?

Comment: of the two evils, iframes are a little better.

Comment: lol XD But i am required to use one of the two. my boss doesn't want a flat <a> link / any other asp.net link. the dousche :<

Comment: @rock Iframes are not an evil. They are a standard component of modern web-applications (Facebook, Youtube, Gmail, etc.). Frames on the other hand are deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore.

Comment: Ok, so maybe not "Evil". But iFrames can be a pain to work with... Especially since you can style them. But you're right. It is a standard way to bring external content into your site. If you can avoid external pages in favor of internal content, then you'll have better flexibility overall. Depending on circumstances, I even prefer pulling external RSS and then formatting it myself internally for advanced flexibility.

Comment: Thumbs to that comment :) I am definitely NOT going to use Frames, but Iframes. I have worked with both before, but the simplicity of implementing a Iframe looked a little dodgy to me. Simple things usually stabs performance in the face with a rubber fork

Comment: I just re read my comment ^ I meant to say "... since you **can't** style them ..."

Comment: It sounds like your boss/client is using this to show other content in their own site's "frame". Keep in mind lots of sites have frame-blocking scripts that will prevent this from working if this is actually the intent.

Comment: That said, there's really no performance issue with an iFrame. It's just an HTML tag that creates a second browser viewport.

Comment: yup, you'd have to also introduce a [frame buster anti-buster](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed) - or something like that.

Comment: Iframes can alo be Used in document buildings.... > Using iframe than frame is good...for your case [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236430/dynamically-insert-iframe-in-a-div)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At this point, go with iFrames:

- iFrame is HTML5. Frameset is obsolete in HTML5.
- You have to load pages into each Frameset. iFrames can be embedded anywhere in a document.
- You can style, hide, resize either, but iFrames are much easier to work with in this regard.

I've seen cases where the developer went with Frameset because he couldn't get the iFrame to size properly, but this isn't too big a deal with a little Javascript (if even that).  The only reason to use a Frameset is if you don't fear it's eventual deprecation with modern browsers, and/or if you can't get iFrames to size the way you want based on the content you're integrating and need a quick solution.

Comment: ...and a few days later, THANKS FOR THE ADVICE! Iframes worked perfectly in my website (under circumstances). Almost ready to launch... :D. I'll keep you posted

Answer (score 0):

If this is about display of 3rd party data in your site, you could use data feeds from the other sites if they're available, or use a screen scraper to extract the information you need, then display it in your own way on the page.

Unless it needs to look exactly like to other page.

Check out this [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210513000146/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/070601-1.shtml) on screen scraping for ASP.NET