# How to insert created object into a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I created an iframe using jQuery that I want to insert into an existing div element. However, when I use innerHTML to insert it, it shows up as: "[object HTMLIFrameElement]"

What could be the reason for this?

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkKramer/PYX5s/2/

Comment: have a look here...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236430/dynamically-insert-iframe-in-a-div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#iframecontainer').append(iframe);
```

instead of

```
var iframediv = document.getElementById('iframecontainer');
iframediv.innerHTML = iframe;
```

should fix the problem

Answer (score 4):

You want to use the appendChild method rather than innerHTML. Change the last line in the JSFiddle from

```
iframediv.innerHTML = iframe;
```

to

```
iframediv.appendChild(iframe);
```

**Edit to actually answer your question:**

Your variable `iframe` is a reference to a DOM element. It's object representation is an `<iframe>` element while its textual representation is simply [object HTMLIFrameElement].

By using `innerHTML` you are attempting to insert its textual representation into the DOM. This is just how the method works. You may come across JS code where elements are added to the DOM via innerHTML, but it's always with text, e.g.

```
element.innerHTML = '<div>some text</div>';
```

In this case the browser will correctly add a `<div>` node as a child of `element`.

For your `<iframe>` element to be inserted into the DOM using the variable `iframe`, you must use the appendChild method which will add the IFrame object as a child node to `iframediv`.

Comment: To further clarify, if you made your iframe variable into a string then you could add it in with innerHTML like so: var iframe = '<iframe width="500" height="300" src="http://www.google.com" style="border:0; margin:0;" scrolling="yes" id="googleiframe" />'; At this point though, you are working with a string and not an actual DOM element, thus no object methods (like setAttribute) can be used on the variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
var new_iframe = $("<iframe></iframe>");

new_iframe.appendTo($("#div_to_insert_into"));
```

Comment: However it is not using my example, if he looked at it he would've seen that I'm not trying just to add an iframe into the div

Comment: I looked. but I don't see a reason of using document.createElement if you have jQuery power at your hands. also solution would work anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The **idea** behind (most) of the posted solutions is that you can work with your iframe and it's container as *jQuery objects* instead of regular dom elements.  A jQuery object is a reference to a `div` or an `iframe` that has access to all of jQuery's awesome methods... like `.append()` and `.click()`.

Generally speaking, jQuery's real purpose is to turn lines of code like

```
var iframediv = document.getElementById('iframecontainer');
```

...into ...

```
var iframediv = $("#iframecontainer");
```

...which you can then use to do with whatever you please, like

```
iframediv.appendTo("#anotherDiv");
```

Good luck.

Comment: Very good informatie answer, I have learned something. Upvote, however I cant accept since it wasn't made exactly in context to my problem.

Comment: just change the last line of your click function from `iframediv.innerHTML = iframe;` to `$(iframediv).append(iframe);` .