# How to show HTML email string in a textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a huge prerendered HTML inside a HTML. The inner HTML is an email template. After pressing a button in the enclosing HTML I would copy the inner HTML to a textarea. But the only content I see when it is performed in the textarea is a `[object Object]`. What is wrong with my implementation?

This is the nested HTML:

```html
        <div class="col-md-6 pb-4">
            <div class="card p-3">
                <h4>Generated Code</h4>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="iframe-textarea" rows="8"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="card mt-2 p-3">
                <h4>Email Preview</h4>

                    #for(readyMadePostContext in campaignContext.readyMadePosts) {
                        <!-- Card -->


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" class="email-post">
   <head>
      <!--[if gte mso 9]>
```

And here I does a jQuery, and paste in the founded HTML:

```js
function updateCode() {
    var postsArray = ""
    $(".email-post").each(function(i, obj) {
        if ($(obj).is(":visible")) {
            postsArray = $(obj)
        }
    });
    $("#iframe-textarea").val(postsArray)
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert created object into a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629166/how-to-insert-created-object-into-a-div)

Answer (score 0):

`postsArray = $(obj)` assigns the a jQuery result set (which is an Object) to `postsArray`.

`$("#iframe-textarea").val(postsArray)` will convert `postsArray` to a string and set the the value of the `textarea` to that string. Converting a jQuery result set to a string results in `[object Object]`.

If you want to get the `html` of the first element in the resultset you have to do `postsArray = $(obj).html()`.

Or because `obj` in this case is a [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) you could just do `postsArray = obj.innerHTML;` (or `outerHTML`, depending on what you need).

Comment: Hi, it works, but it fills only the content of the HTML, so starting at the `<head>..`. Do you know how can I take the `<html xmlns ..` part also? I tried to call `parent()`, like `postsArray = $(obj).parent().innerHTML` and `postsArray = $(obj).parent().html()` also, none of them worked.

Comment: `innerHTML` of `html` would not contain the `html` tag, but `html` will always be the root element. So you would need - as mentioned - to use `outerHTML`.

Comment: Do you know maybe why `outerHTML` is special, why I need `[0]` index before to get it to work? `postsArray = $(obj)[0].outerHTML`

Comment: @János As I said `$(obj)` is a jQuery resultset. The resultset set contains 0…n elements.  `outerHTML`  is not special. You also need `[0]` if you want to use `innerHTML` in that case. But  jQuery provides an `html()` function that maps to `innerHTML`. But it doesn't have a function that maps to `outerHTML`, likely because `val`, `text`, `html` are both setters and getters, and setting the `outerHTML` could be problematic in the sense of a resultset. That's why I said that you can directly work on `obj`.